# Apply condition in Power Query (Filter earliest date based on each Consol ID) - PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I would like to apply some condition when do the data cleansing in Power BI Power Query.

[PowerBI- Power Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvSzz.png)

**Only need one date record for each CONSOL ID**

[Conditions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9rFa.png)

ETD (DD/MM/YYYY)

Condition as below:

i.) Date with 'Null' shouldn't be chosen as earliest date when there have available date for that CONSOL ID.

**For example:  C001 with date '1/1/2021' should be selected as earliest date, but C002 doesn't have other available date. In this case, 'Null' can be selected.**

ii.) If the CONSOL ID have few transport mode (SEA or AIR ,RAI,ROA), ONLY priorities on the earliest date of 'SEA' or 'AIR' transport mode.

**For example: In C003, even the earliest date is 1/1/2021, but we only focus on the date with transport mode 'SEA' or 'AIR'. So earliest date for C003 is 1/3/2021, while C004 is 1/6/2021.**

iii.) If there is only one transport mode (Doesn't matter is RAI or ROA), the earliest date will be selected.

**For example: '1/1/2021' for C005 and C006.**

Here attached with the pbix: https://ufile.io/twdwgzh8

Thanks for your attention.

Any assistance you can provide would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this below **Measure**

```
earliest = 

var current_row_consolid = min(your_table_name[ConsolID])
var current_row_transport = min(your_table_name[Transport])

var earliest_sea_air =
CALCULATE(
    min(your_table_name[ETD]),
    FILTER(
        ALLEXCEPT(your_table_name,your_table_name[ConsolID]),
        your_table_name[Transport] = "SEA" || your_table_name[Transport] = "AIR"
    )
)

var earliest_others =
CALCULATE(
    min(your_table_name[ETD]),
    FILTER(
        ALLEXCEPT(your_table_name,your_table_name[ConsolID]),
        your_table_name[Transport] <> "SEA" && your_table_name[Transport] <> "AIR"
    )
)

return
if(
    ISBLANK(earliest_sea_air),
    earliest_others,
    earliest_sea_air
)
```

Here is the final output-

[image]